# Is possible to make this SQL query run faster?

Tags: mysql

**Two simple tables**

**Base** table

```
+--------+
|id|value|
+--------+
|  |     |
+--------+
```

**Event** table (with a lot of data..)

```
+--------------+
|id|event| date|
+--------------+
|  |     |     |
+--------------+
```

Then I would like to have a list of all *base.value* with corresponding to their **last** *events* (including values without event entries)

```
+----------------+
|id|lastEvt|value|
+----------------+
|  |       |     |
+----------------+
```

This is a (working but) *very slow* attempt

```
SELECT *
  FROM  ( 
    SELECT base.id,
           event.event,
           base.value
      FROM base
           LEFT OUTER JOIN event
                        ON base.id = event.id
     ORDER BY event.date DESC
) 
AS res
 GROUP BY res.id;
```

I suspect there is a better/faster way of doing the query, but I don't know how..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT b.id, b.value, e.event
    FROM base b
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date) AS LastEventDate
                       FROM event
                       GROUP BY id) q
            INNER JOIN event e
                ON q.id = e.id
                    AND q.LastEventDate = e.date
            ON b.id = q.id
```

Comment: Could you please modify it to show only the three columns: id, (last)event, and base.value? So then I can verify result is correct and do benchmark. Thanks

Comment: sorry if I insist but the result should show the "last event" but not the "date of last event"

Comment: @void That's a horse of a different color then! I've modified the answer.

Comment: @Johan Please refrain from editing my answer. The final join on `b.id = q.id` is correct. Note that I have nested the INNER JOIN within the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, the indentation you use makes it very hard to understand the query. Personally I find it worse to read than no indentation at all.

Comment: @johan I'm not interested in quibbling about indentation. You changed the join condition which fundamentally altered the answer.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, that must have been my butterfingers sorry 'bout that, I only wanted to add and delete spaces. I noticed the nested join you used to force the join order. The answer would really improve if you actually explained how that nesting works, because I think 95% of the people will miss the subtleties in that.

Comment: Well, I've finally tried this, and it's twice faster than original, so this is *a* correct answer +1. Although the query keeps being slow, so I think I have to check about indexing, configuration, partitioning, etc.. If it were a raw file instead of DB/SQL, I'd known what to do, (start searching from the end to backward in the event file, it would be faster, except for the unlikely situation that there were a single event of an ID at the beginning and then no more, but that is unlikely for this database). Is there special way to manage a (always growing) event logging?

Comment: I forgot to say, it's solved now : **by not doing the query**, mantaining latest data directly into a new table

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
b.id, b.value, e.event
FROM Base b 
LEFT JOIN Event e ON (b.id = e.id)
ORDER BY e.date DESC
GROUP BY b.id
```

I assume you have proper indexes on both of those tables.

Comment: no, they aren't really indexed, perhaps that's the background problem

Comment: final "GROUP BY b.id", give me syntax error in mysql I couldn't test it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems as though this should work:

```
SELECT base.id, 
       base.value, 
       event.date 
FROM 
       base 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           event ON base.id = event.id 
ORDER BY event.date DESC 
GROUP BY base.id
```

As far as whether or not the query above is faster, I assume it would be because it does not include any subqueries, however you'd have to benchmark to verify.

Comment: final "GROUP BY base.id", give me syntax error in mysql I couldn't test it